# How front running bots can see private transactions sent via FlashBots?

Tags: frontrunning

just an example of sandwich attack on a private transaction sent via FlashBots. How the front running bot could see the transaction if it should be private?

[image: bot attack:]

[image: victim transaction]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot. That will destroy the purpose of using private txs / Flashbots. What's happening here is the tx was taken from the mempool, made into a bundle and sent to Flashbots. Etherscan will detect and tag the txs in the bundle as private txs, so even if they have the private tx tag, doesn't mean that they were actually private.